# How to get output like SQLPLUS while Running SQL Query in shell script

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have a following shell script

```
RETVAL=`sqlplus -silent user/password <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 9990

SELECT   id, type, count(*) "count" FROM event

EXIT;
EOF`

echo $RETVAL
```

it output like

ID TYPE count ------------- ---------- ----------- 2 11 2 1 4 1 2 10 29 1 1 35 2 1 6 2 18 1 2 2 3 7 rows selected

But i want output like

```
ID              TYPE        count
------------- ---------- -----------
        2         11           2
        1          4           1
        2         10          29
        1          1          35
        2          1           6
        2         18           1
        2          2           3
```

7 rows selected.

I tried to figure out if i get some new line character but couldnt find it.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable contains the newlines, but the way you're displaying it removes them.

Replace the `echo` statement with:

```
echo "$RETVAL"
```

The shell won't mess with the newlines then. You should pretty much always quote variables that can contain any form of whitespace that needs to be preserved.